# Transform list to the dictionary

Tags: list, dictionary

I have a list with a strings
['scene-task-v001-user', 'scene-task-v002-user', 'scene-explo-v001-user', 'scene-train-v001-user', 'scene-train-v002-user']

strings created by regular expression
'`(?P<scene>\w+)-(?P<task>\w+)-v(?P<ver>\d{3,})-(?P<user>\w+)`'

I need to create dictionary where key its a task group and values contain all ver groups with the same task
{'task': ['001', '002'], 'explo': ['001'], 'train': ['001', '002']}

How to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `('t-1', 't-2', 's-1', 'z-1', 'z-2')` is a tuple, not a list. In addition, `{'t': {'1', '2'}, 's': {'1'}, 'z': {'1', '2'}}` is wrong expression, a form of the values would be a list here, not {}. I corrected this issue in my codes below.

1. Instead of using regular expression, you can loop the list and split by '-' inside the loop to get keys and values, as follows:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

l = ('t-1', 't-2', 's-1', 'z-1', 'z-2')

d = defaultdict(list)

for item in l:
    key, val = item.split('-')
    d[key].append(val)

print(d) # defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'t': ['1', '2'], 's': ['1'], 'z': ['1', '2']})
print(d['t']) # ['1', '2']
```

2. Using regular expressions to get keys and values for a dictionary:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
import re

l = ('t-1', 't-2', 's-1', 'z-1', 'z-2')

d = defaultdict(list)

for item in l:
    key_patten = re.compile('\w-')
    val_patten = re.compile('-\w')
    key = key_patten.search(item).group().replace('-', '')
    val = val_patten.search(item).group().replace('-', '')
    d[key].append(val)

print(d) # defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'t': ['1', '2'], 's': ['1'], 'z': ['1', '2']})
print(d['t']) # ['1', '2']
```

Comment: Well, format of the strings more complicated then in example and I need to use regular expression to take what I need,

Comment: @AndriiBelskyi Then it would be helpful if you provide sample formats so that people can make appropriate regular expressions for you.

Comment: String format looks like this:
scene-task-v001-user
scene-task-v002-user
scene-explo-v001-user

I using regular expression:
(?P<scene>\w+)-(?P<task>\w+)-v(?P<ver>\d{3,})(-(?P<desc>\w+))?-(?P<user>\w+)

I need only groups task and ver and I need to create dictionary where task contain all ver variations

Comment: @AndriiBelskyi To make regular expression, much detail is helpful. In addition to that key, value are seperated by '-', are there any other conditions? such as how long the key variables? Does key variables can include numbers? and so on.

Comment: So, another process create this strings by regular expression I wrote, then I read list of strings and I need to make dictionary with task group as a key and all ver groups with the same task as a value. In my case task group always contain characters, ver group - numbers

Comment: @AndriiBelskyi I added a new code using regular expressions to make a expected output.

Comment: @AndriiBelskyi Does it answer your question? If this helped solve your problem, pls mark this answer as accepted, so that this can help other users know this question is solved by this answer.